# How do you set the active tracks via a chromecast receiver while media is loading?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm developing a [custom media receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) for chromecast.  Is it possible to set the active tracks on media load?  For example, I have two embedded audio tracks, and I want the second audio track to be what plays immediately on load.  The sender does not know what embedded tracks are available, so using the [LoadRequest](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest) is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for this was added in the 2.0.0 receiver release on Dec 1, 2014: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes

Documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#loadTracksInfo